# Wrong breakpoint being hit

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, console-application, breakpoints

Sorry if this question was answered already, but I didn't found anything relevant. I'm experiencing a strange issue in Visual Studio 2013 C++ Win32 application when debugger incorrectly hits the breakpoint. Here is a sample code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i >= 1; i--)
        if (i % 2)
            a = a*a;
    b++;
    return b;
}
```

I set breakpoint on `b++` line. I'm familiar with debugging and breakpoints when debugging c# code (and very beginner in c++) and based on my experience, the breakpoint on `b++` line should be hit only when for loop is ended. However it hits for each loop iteration, but the code (increment) doesn't execute.
Here is a screenshot of VS with relevant information
[image]

Comment: Are you running a Release configuration? It may be possible that some of your lines are optimized away and the line-numbers in your PDB doesn't match, just a guess. For this reason we often use _Noopt_ builds, which are basically the same as Release, but with optimization disabled (assuming we don't want to use the full Debug configuration of course).

Comment: try to clean up and check if you have a Release build.

Comment: 1) no, I'm running in debug mode. 2) result in locals is correct, but at this point the breakpoint should not be hit.

Comment: I cleaned entire solution, but nothing changed, breakpoint on that line hits each loop iteration. When switching to release mode -- VS hits the non-existent breakpoint on return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this code is ok and should work as you expected.
VS allows you to place a breakpoint at the end of an execution block (the `if` statement inside the `for` loop in this case).

[image]

As you did not wrap the `if` statement with curly braces (as in the image above), VS assumes that the breakpoint you placed in the `b++` statement refers to the end of the `for` execution block and therefore breaks, without executing the `b++` statement.

Comment: do I understand correctly that if execution block (loops, if statements, etc.) is without braces, then breakpoint after execution block means the end of this block and not actual line?

Comment: Actually it means both, i.e. the program will stop at this statement either as it is the end of the statement block or you completed the loop and therefore reached this statement.

Comment: BTW, as a rule of thumb I'd recommend you to always use curly braces, even when these are not required. This improves readability and also prevents stupid errors of adding other statement below the `for`/`if` statement and expecting these to be part of their respective execution block.

Comment: Thanks. In C# I'm always using braces, but I got this example exactly as is.

Comment: If you look at the disassembly (Ctrl-Alt-D) of the program without the braces, you will see that the breakpoint of the b++ is on the jmp: not the mov instruction.  If you then look at the one with the braces, you will see that the breakpoint of the b++ is on the mov instruction.  You could set the breakpoint in the disassembled version so that it stops when it is outside the loop.